# How could i make CSS apply to all in a div?

Tags: html, css

Say

```
<style>
#id{
 text-align:center;
 color:orange;
}
</style>

<div id="id">
<a href="http://url.url/">Click</a>
</div>
```

So I would like it to apply `color:orange;` to the `<a>` tag, but it does not, how could I do this?

The `<a>` applys, but `color:orange;` does not.

Example: [Codepen example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bBorEd)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually this is not necessary because `color` is an inherited property. However, links have a color defined by default in the user agent stylesheet, so they don't inherit. You only need to use a more specific selector than that default one.

```css
#id, #id * {
  text-align:center;
  color:orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="id">
  <a href="http://url.url/">Click</a>
</div>
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks for the answer and explanation. :)

Answer (score 1):

Please use this code if you want to apply styling for both parent and all links inside:

```
#id, #id a {
  text-align:center;
  color:orange;
}
```

More specific selector has higher priority (in the example above: `#id a`) than user agent styles.

To be specific according to the title of your question - you want to apply styles to all elements in a div, thus the rule should look like this:

```
div * {
  text-align:center;
  color:orange;
}
```

Comment: I see how that would work, but the point of me using <div> is to only apply it to that one id.

Comment: It would be great if you added an explanation to your code

Answer (score 0):

Add the color to an

`a {
color:orange;
}`

Answer (score 0):

```css
#id {
  text-align: center;
  color: orange;
}

#id * {
  text-align: inherit;
  color: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could this be what you're looking for?

```
<style>
#id{
 text-align:center;
 color:orange;
}
</style>

<div id="id">
<a id = "id" href="http://url.url/">Click</a>
</div>
```